# Perl: Redirect STDOUT to two files

Tags: perl, redirect, io, stream, stdout

How can I redirect the `STDOUT` stream to two files (duplicates) within my Perl script? Currently I am just streaming into a single log file:

```
open(STDOUT, ">$out_file") or die "Can't open $out_file: $!\n";
```

What do I have to change? Thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use [`IO::Tee`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Tee).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Tee;

open(my $fh1,">","tee1") or die $!;
open(my $fh2,">","tee2") or die $!;

my $tee=IO::Tee->new($fh1,$fh2);

select $tee; #This makes $tee the default handle.

print "Hey!\n"; #Because of the select, you don't have to do print $tee "Hey!\n"
```

And yes, the output works:

```
> cat tee1
Hey!
> cat tee2
Hey!
```

Comment: Where did the OP ask to replace `STDOUT` (...and with what?  0_o).  OP wanted to "redirect the `STDOUT` stream to two files".

Comment: By `select`ing `$tee`, `$tee` becomes the default handle.  TIMTOWTDI, whether you like it or not.

Comment: I'm really really blind. Deleteing my compeltey false comments!

Comment: `->new($fh1,$fh2)` should be `->new($fh1,\*STDOUT)`

Comment: Note: That won't work if someone references STDOUT directly or if they call `system`.

Answer (score 4):

[File::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTee) provides the functionality you need.

```
use File::Tee qw( tee );
tee(STDOUT, '>', 'stdout.txt');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `tee` PerlIO layer.

```
use PerlIO::Util;
*STDOUT->push_layer(tee => "/tmp/bar");
print "data\n";

$ perl tee_script.pl > /tmp/foo
$ cat /tmp/foo
data
$ cat /tmp/bar
data
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a Unix-like system, use the [*tee*](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html) utility.

```
$ perl -le 'print "Hello, world"' | tee /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
Hello, world

$ cat /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
Hello, world
Hello, world
```

To set up this duplication from within your program, set up a pipe from your `STDOUT` to an external *tee* process. Passing `"|-"` to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) makes this easy to do.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @copies = qw( /tmp/foo /tmp/bar );

open STDOUT, "|-", "tee", @copies or die "$0: tee failed: $!";

print "Hello, world!\n";

close STDOUT or warn "$0: close: $!";
```

Demo:

```
$ ./stdout-copies-demo
Hello, world!

$ cat /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Two files only (no screen): `perl ... | tell /tmp/foo > /tmp/bar`

Comment: I want to redirect within script. Currently I am just having one log file:

open(STDOUT, ">$out_file") or die "Can't open $out_file: $!\n";

What do I have to change?